# Django: AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'reqister'

Tags: python, django

So I am starting with Django and I am working on the Django tutorial-project, that includes a poll application. The tutorial gave me the Code:
    from django.contrib import admin

```
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

But when I add this to my code and try it out it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'reqister'
```

My admin.py file looks exactly like this and without this code everything is running fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct method name is `register`, you typed `reqister`.